# Is it safe to flush it?

Tags: chevrolet, coolant, cavalier, flush

I've got a 1989 Chevy Cavalier sedan. 78,000 k. Previous owner let it sit for 7 years. I've drained and replaced the oil, fuel filter, hoses and such.

But my coolant tank is completely encrusted in about 1/2 inch brown crust. Solid not muddy. I was going to do a coolant/radiator flush. Can I flush it wothout getting crap stuck in my radiator and making it worse? Do I need to do more than just flush it?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing it in bits. Remove both the header tank and the radiator from the car, and flush them out separately, then flush out the engine while they're out. You may well need to replace the hoses, if it's been sat for that long they will probably have perished - don't forget the little ones that go to the heater matrix as well.